# Can part of an API call be replaced with a prop value in ReactJS?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, jsx

I have an API call via a local JSON file in the child component.

In the parent component I want to have something like this:

```
<ComponentA value={test} />
```

In my component with the API call I want to do the following:

```
{DataFromJson.test.map(a => a)}
```

Data in json is in the following format:

```
{test:[{value: 1}], test2:[{value:2}]}
```

So that test is a value that is appended to DataFromJson (and whenever a value is passed to the component `test` changes to whatever value).

Is there a workable solution around this?

https://codesandbox.io/s/serene-moon-zrn07?file=/src/App.js

Comment: Slight distraction:  Can `DataFromJson.test.map(a => a)` be just `DataFromJson.test`?  Why use an identity `.map`?

Comment: Can you share some demo or a codesandbox link of your issue? That'll help to understand your issue easily. And from the child component you can access any parent values which is passed using `props`, You can use `Object.entries(props.value).map`

Comment: @Wyck it can, I was just showing how I was using it in the component.

Comment: @SifatHaque I want to be able to change the value of test depending on what's being passed down from the component.

Comment: Do you mean that in the `ComponentA`, you want to listen for the value of `value` changes, and update it accordingly in `DataFromJson`?

Comment: @jarrett Yes! Can this be done via props?

Comment: @SifatHaque https://codesandbox.io/s/serene-moon-zrn07?file=/src/App.js

Comment: Yes, you can receive the value of `value` via props in the `ComponentA`. Then i believe you could use a `useEffect` to listen for changes and update it accordingly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually i think you are trying to access the value dynamically. You want to pass a value from the parent and see the result in child component accordingly. If i'm right about this. Then you need to use
`{dataJson[props.value].map((a) => a.value)}` to get that data dynamically.

If you pass `<Info value="exampleTwo" />`
then the output will show `test2`

If you pass `<Info value="exampleOne" />`
then the output will show `test`

And to update you can use

```
  useEffect(() => {
    setDataJson((prevData) => ({ ...prevData, ...newData }));
  }, [newData]);
```

I've added the update code in the codesandbox link.

Here is the working solution [codesandbox-link](https://codesandbox.io/s/spring-sound-utyip?file=/src/Info.js)

Answer (score 0):

You could use an `useEffect` to listen for changes in props passed in:

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import Data from "./data.json";

const Info = (props) => {
  const [dataJson, setDataJson] = useState(Data);

  useEffect(() => {
    // useEffect to listen for changes in props.value 
    // Update data here using `setDataJson()`
    
  }, [props.value]);

  return <div>{/* Display */}</div>;
};

export default Info;
```